# Access 2002/VBA - how to populate subform from query to allow user to select a row

Tags: ms-access, vba

Consider:

I have a form I need to display payment events for individual clients on.  I do not want to display all columns in the payment table, I want user-friendly column names, and I want Access to display a popup form that displays information should the user click on a row of the form (a payment event).

Firstly, I am unsure whether Access 2002 and VBA will allow me to do this.  Secondly, I am unsure how to make the individual payment events on the form clickable.

I assume I can do something like:

```
strSQL = "SELECT payment.payment_id, payment_amount AS Amount, payment_date AS Date" & _
"FROM contact_payment, payment " & _
"WHERE contact_payment.contact_id =" & forms([ContactForm].contact_id & _
"AND payment.payment_id = contact_payment.payment_id"
```

in order to get the data for the clickable form.  Is this the correct way, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the form's `DblClick` event (or `Click` event) to open a new form:

```
Private Sub Form_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMoreInfo", , , "ID = " & ID
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @E Mett - that sounds like the way to go! I will try this solution out and accept your answer.